# JavaScript set scrollHeight

Tags: javascript, properties

In JavaScript what's the right way to set the scrollHeight of one element to that of another element? Direct assignment has no effect.
Thanks, Greg

Answer (score 14):

It's not possible directly. The scrollHeight is a read only property that contain the total height of element content in pixels.

If have element A and you want to have element B with the same scrollHeight as element A, make it so that element B has a single child DIV element (move all previous element B content as child nodes of the DIV) that is set to:

```
width : 100%;
overflow : hidden;
```

and using javascript set the height of DIV to scrollHeight of element A (in pixels):

```
document.getElementById('B').childNodes.item(0).style.height = document.getElementById('A').scrollHeight + 'px';
```