# Change Element ScrollWidth

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a case in which I need to change the `scrollHeight` and `scrollWidth` of an element. Is there any way that I could set this value?

The options below didn't worked I think beacuse these are getters no setters:

```
document.getElementById('test').scrollWidth = 3000;
```

jQuery Way:

```
$('#long')[0].scrollWidth = 2000;
```

Comment: I think this has been answered already here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1608793/javascript-set-scrollheight

Comment: Thanks that question has the answer. It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

If "test" div has scrollbar, i.e (overflow-x: scroll) or (overflow-x: auto)

```
$("#test").get(0).scrollLeft = 3000  //jquery
document.getElementById("test").scrollLeft(3000); //js
```

scrollWidth property is readonly

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to change the scrollHeight or scrollWidth of an Element. But the solution suggested by "qbeuek" in the question linked below could be a way out of this in my case.

[Link for the suggested answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1608793/javascript-set-scrollheight)